# How to load a video from memory when using opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing a service that receives a video as a parameter (Base64 file).
I want to start working with the video from memory since I already have it, and NOT write it to a file and then load it with `cv2.VideoCapture()`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: i found that this can't happen yous should write to disk then read the file